# how to make all image responsive in wordpress with css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a theme in word-press by using bootstrap . Everything is working fine when using it in word-press theme . But getting issue with images as they are not getting responsive class so how can i make them responsive like featured images and images inside the content as they are going here and there in mobile.

in my css i used this

```
img {
 border: 0 none!important;
 max-width: 100%!important;
 vertical-align: middle!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, use `class="img-responsive"`, which is provided by bootstrap for responsive images.

Comment: client cant use img-responsive every time to make images responsive..So  i want to make a global setting for all images ..

Comment: Use the styling which is in "img-responsive". That is: .img-responsive{ display:block; max-width:100%; height:auto}